# Bridge rectifier transformer sides reversed

Tags: rectifier, bridge

what will happen at circuit output of a bridge rectifier if the ac supply is connected to secondary  and rest of the circuit is connected to primary winding of transformer? Please give me the circuit according to question on multisim

Comment: Nothing will happen because you did not include a circuit diagram.

Answer (score 1):

> if the ac supply is connected to secondary and rest of the circuit is
>   connected to primary winding of transformer?

The transformer will suffer damage - putting a normal mains AC supply on the secondary will produce heavy core saturation and a fuse will blow. Transformers are only designed to have mains AC supplies connected to the primary winding.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a step-down transformer (120V -> 24V for example), the reversed transformer will act as a step-up transformer, providing 600 volts to the rectifier, for my example transformer.

If the transformer actually works, the rectifier and following circuits will be destroyed by the excessive voltage.  As Andy aka says, the transformer itself may be damaged, and may not produce the expected 600 volts.  In general, Very Bad Things will happen.